# Highcharts - DataLabels connector customization {Straight line}

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I am using Highcharts...

How can I customize dataLabels line connector like below?

Tried with `softConnector: false`, but not getting the desired result though.

Any help highly appreciated as I am struck on this :(

**[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L6ywtj7z/)**

> **Regular connector after using** `softConnector: false,`

[image: Original]

> **What I am expecting**

[image]

Comment: You have added softConnector parameter in wrong place, it should be inside dataLabels object. Here you can find an example how it will work then: http://jsfiddle.net/L6ywtj7z/1/

Comment: @Blachlinski... Thanks for correcting me.. But still I am not getting the desired result...

Comment: Well, right, because that's not how Highcharts draws the connectors. I would guess the best options are either 1) draw your own connectors with the `renderer()`, or 2) modify the Highcharts function that draws the connectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap pie.prototype.drawDataLabels method and inside this method you can change the parameters used by your connector.

This is a part you need to change:

```
connectorPath = softConnector ? [
          M,
          x + (labelPos[6] === 'left' ? 5 : -5), y, // end of the string at the label
          'C',
          x, y, // first break, next to the label
          2 * labelPos[2] - labelPos[4], 2 * labelPos[3] - labelPos[5],
          labelPos[2], labelPos[3], // second break
          L,
          labelPos[4], labelPos[5] // base
        ] : [
          M,
          x + (labelPos[6] === 'left' ? 5 : -5), y, // end of the string at the label
          L,
          labelPos[4], y, // second break
          L,
          labelPos[4], labelPos[5] // base
        ];
```

And here you can find an example how your chart will work with this wrap: http://jsfiddle.net/L6ywtj7z/5/

EDIT: After changes in Highcharts drawDataLabels method, it is possible to solve your issue much easier, using connectorPath method: http://jsfiddle.net/L6ywtj7z/15

Comment: **@Blachlinkski**... Excellent, this is what exactly I am looking for... Thank you so much for your time... I am **Upvoting** ad **Accepting** your answer... Keep up the good work

Comment: Yes, after some changes in drawDataLabels method, this issue may be solved much easier, using connectorPath method: http://jsfiddle.net/L6ywtj7z/15/

Comment: Thank you very much @GrzegorzBlachliński, you made my day ! Works like a charm !

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński, actually I want dataLabels as this image http://i.imgur.com/M0PMvIY.png . Can you help me ?

Comment: So you would like to get similar connectors to shown in this example? http://jsfiddle.net/L6ywtj7z/18/